# Testing of complex systems

Tags: empiricism, thought-experiment, experience, measurement-theory, experiment

I wasn't sure were to post this question, seems ill fitted for most content I see.

In software development there is a procedure for testing software that includes unit testing, integration testing, system testing and acceptance testing.

In a way you could loosely apply this general guideline for testing other things that are not software, like a car (check individual components, check the interaction of those components, check the whole system, check customer acceptance etc).

I was wondering, could there be a general structure for the testing of any system? At the end of the day I think we are always trying to measure system properties, and the functions they perform (which could also be defined as properties). Is there a general pattern for this kind of tasks? something that could be applied repeatedly which is not specific to a certain domain? I think this is also strongly related to measurement.

Comment: I think the underlying principle is to break down a complex system in terms of sub-systems/components so that you can test those components. The decomposition can be recursive. The principle stems from a practical concern IMHO.

Comment: I guess at the end of the day you are trying to model a complex system, so as to predict if it will perform well. If a certain component fails it is likely that the whole system fails, but what if through emergence a component failling makes the whole system better? then unit testing is wrong, so what you are actually doing is trying to predict the whole system behaviour. If this is true and modelling the whole system is required, given that the universe is a complex system itself, what I'm asking for might be interpreted as a way to simplify reality (at least partially).

Comment: You might want to look for a forum on systems theory or systems engineering.

Comment: @gabriel - this is very handy - let's skip unit testing and hope that emergence will result in even better systems ;-) Would you fly in a plane where the engineers used that methodology to test the engines?

Answer (score 1):

Your question conflates testing and measurement, which are two overlapping but separate activities. Testing might or might not involve measurement, and measurement might or might not be for the purpose of testing.

The purpose of software testing is to check that the software works as intended- that implies the existence of a specification or statement of requirements to which the working of the software can be compared. UAT implies the existence of an intended user. Measurements might be performed without regard for any specification or intended use. I might measure the height of a mountain, say, just to know what it is. I might measure characteristics of a complicated system, such as a cell, to get insights into how it works, not to test it in any way.

Leaving that generality aside, another challenge for your idea is that not every system of interest breaks down into functional units. Consider a volcanic eruption, for example- I might be intensely interested in assessing the behaviour of volcanoes, but modelling them conceptually as systems of integrated units is unlikely to add any value, and quite how the concept of UAT might apply to vulcanology is a puzzle to say the least.

It seems to me that the way in which tests might be organised for software  could also be a good way to organise tests for any other type of system which, like software, is formed from the integration of functional units for the purpose of performing overall functions for an intended set of users, and is of limited use for anything else.

Comment: A test could be a form of measurement, where the systems answers with the measurement values yes or no to some "measure" on it, the question being "does it work as intended per the spec?" and we "measure" "yes" or "no" in response.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your comment for the most part. Nonetheless, modelling any system as integrated units, albeit burdensome at first glance might be inevitable in any complex system. This reminds me of Stephen Wolfram's "A New Kind of Science". My question was from a practical point of view, really (at least initially) but by posting it in a philosophy forum is hard to not get swept away with all the ideas and implications. I want to know if there is a generalizable procedure that simplifies the testing of complex systems. The closest thing I found is separating the system into units, like UAT.

Comment: @gabriel Yes, the generic tool we have is to break down the complexity with "divide and conquer": break down into smaller pieces, tackle those, then reassemble.

Comment: @Frank [Functional_decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition) actually, I think my question was even more broad than I expected, It seems knowledge itself might be inherently hierarchical. I still wonder if there is something more besides simple functional decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

In the philosophy of computer science, philosophers are starting to really examine the exact relationship between testing hardware and software as physical artifacts as well as understand the role of design, implementation, correctness, and performance of computation devices from a philosophical bent. Of course, when you're talking about UAT/RT and the like, you're talking about a form of [empiricism (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationalism-empiricism/) according to traditional philosophy accounts. Unlike using [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) to deductively prove that the function intended in the system is adequate, unit testing requires actually designing and writing code to ensure that the physical system performs as intended. One can have beautiful mathematical proofs of correctness, but if Intel puts out a chip with a [floating point error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug), the software might not work as intended. Thus, philosophically speaking, UAT/RT is a form of [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence) as it relies on the senses and tools and methods that hone the senses.

Unfortunately, the design of empirical tests is domain specific and the informal logic applies to reasoning defeasibly about it is also domain specific. Toulmin makes the case in his [*Uses of Argument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Toulmin#The_Toulmin_model_of_argument) that warrants in reasoning, be they empirical or otherwise, depend on what one is reasoning about, and that is simply because there are [normative elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) in argumentation. The design of testing is the same way because what is being tested for is a function of the intention of the designer. (See [Parson's *Philosophy of Design* (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NjtcCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=the%20philosophy%20of%20design&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO17bup5P9AhUYjIkEHfVHBicQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=the%20philosophy%20of%20design&f=false) for more information.)

Philosophers of scientists give a lot of thought to what is experimentation, the fancy word for the testing of things in the physical world, and major arguments have been had over what exactly constitutes ways to know what is true. Three traditional terms associated with the import of tests are confirmation, verification, and [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability). Quine famously put forth an extended argument about confirmation called [confirmation holism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism) in an attempt to show that proof must be systematic, and that no one claim itself is subject to truth conditions in a vacuum.

Since there are so many perspectives [on what science is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem), and each has its own position on the relationship between experiment and theory, I'm afraid there might not even be agreement on what experiment is among thinkers like Quine, Latour, Hacking, Gooding, and Popper, for instance. I think if we whittle down, we might be able to make some simple claims:

- Experiment varies from discipline to discipline
- Experiment produces new knowledge
- Experiment occurs in the physical world but it is interpreted by experimenters
- Experiment helps to minimize [underdetermination of theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermination)

Thus, experimentation finds a home in the simplified model of the scientific method. Of course, there are philosophers of every shape and size, and what counts as empirical is a whole 'nother can of worms in deciding what experimentation is. For instance, mathematical empiricists believe that even math is completely built as a body of knowledge from some form of sensory experience.

Thus, like there being no-one-true scientific method, there is also no-one-true experimental method, and each paradigm rests on the theory of the discipline. As a quick example, consider the difference between the hard and social sciences. Both impose the criterion of experimental verification on their bodies of work, but constructing an apparatus to find particles is nothing like designing a psychometric, even though both may rely on philosophical [operationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operationalization) to deal with bridging mind-body duality. And then each discipline has infighting over what constitutes adequate theory and testing. For instance, I know an authority in forensic psychology who absolutely repudiates Meyer-Brigg, though many organizational psychologists swear by it. In that case, both the theory and the psychometric administered by the theory are in dispute.

So, if you ask if there's a general method of testing, you more or less have to include with it the [domain of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse). Is there a general method for psychometry according to psychologists? Is there a general method for proof of correctness among computer scientists? Is there a general method of assaying diseases according to medical doctors? And even then, you'll find that not everyone agrees.

Comment: I dont agree with the conclusion. But I have to give it a bit more thought. Actually, you mentioning confirmation holism, gave me the notion that even a theory is a system in a way. Almost everything is a system. Even your answer to my question is a system (arguments, words, sentences), where every component serves a purpose, therefore I could, in a way perform testing on them for what they try to achieve! (choosing the right words for example). Well, at least every component in every system is countable.

Comment: "no-one-true scientific method" is questionable, and you seem to contradict that when you say that both hard and social sciences impose a criterion of experimental verification. Isn't that the essence of the method itself?

Comment: @gabriel You needn't agree. If you don't, the next step in the critical thinking process is merely to examine why. This is philosophy and makes the process intellectually productive. Since you're fascinated with systems theory, which is sort of an approach that considers the aspect of numerosity in [mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/) philosophically speaking. Systems language contains {system, boundary, interior, exterior, element, relation, etc.} but might also raise an interest in [mathematical structuralism](https://iep.utm.edu/m-struct/)...

Comment: My interests are rooted in philosophy in language, and language can be seen as a somewhat normative approach to creating systems of thought. My answer doesn't deny systems exist, or that complex systems exist, merely that there is no theory (that I'm aware of) that generalizes experimentation across all systems, complex or otherwise). If that's what you disagree with, merely show me the theory of testing you claim spans psychology, physics, biology, chemistry, and sociology. Then my conclusion is plainly wrong. If you can't, then it behooves you to at least explain why you believe it exists...

Comment: without an instance-as-extension.

Comment: @Frank No-one-true-scientific-method may be questionable to you, but it's a matter of fact that it's a central preoccupation of professional philosophers of science. No book IMNSHO makes a better case than [Zammitto's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXxK6e07ciUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zammitto&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiouL3XypX9AhWukokEHbJnDAYQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=zammitto&f=false). Of course, if you come to the table armed with more than your hunches, simply cite the expert that you rely on for guidance.

Comment: That's why the use of language such as "generalized scientific method" certainly would be useful in describing your views. Certainly all methods demarcated as a scientific method would have an experimentation phase. This post simply asserts that there is no way to generally (outside a theory such as the theory of the atom) to posit what experiment consists of. The term 'empirical test' only makes sense when taken from the perspective of a domain.

Comment: Of course, one might argue that a "general scientific method" as taught in high school may be a general form of testing, and a specific form of problem solving. I'll give that some thought.

Comment: @JD I think the essential bit for "scientific method" is that there be some sort of verification that will be authoritative and agreed upon by all. How experiments are actually conducted to arrive at verification is a "detail" - as long as they provide an unquestionable verification step. What is "not scientific" is to skip experimental verification.

Comment: "Methods" of experimentation, theorizing ... certainly vary at a practical level but I'm not looking at that as the "scientific method" as much as the principle that claims need to be checked against experiments AND that we are trying to get some consensus. Maybe that's not what is understood by "scientific method", but good enough for me, given that's it's not even universal - maybe people think they can do "science" without checking their claims against experiments.

Comment: @Frank Well, the real problem with pseudoscientists is not that they claim they can do science without checking results (they're easy to detect), but that what they claim to be and what you claim to accept as experimentation is radically different. Which is the point of my post. There is no generalized notion of experimentation outside of a domain-specific theory.

Comment: @JD Not really, but I mean, how could there be "one way to do experiments"? We can try to figure out commonalities, but someone experimenting on microbes and someone experiment with particles seem to face wildly different challenges? Maybe I'm failing to see the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142874/discussion-between-j-d-and-frank).

Comment: @gabriel Any luck coming up with a general methodology for testing complex systems other than "break up into smaller pieces"? Certainly decomposition is the part of any activity to tackle complexity, including comprehension, but I still don't see a response here from anyone that there exists a formulation of such a generalized methodology applicable to all domains of knowledge.

Comment: @JD well, not yet but I decided to read (or skim) "The Sciences of the Artificial" by Herbert Simon. I'm learning a lot about complex systems, also this has something to do with some statistical analysis I'm performing. I think this is a very fertile ground for ideas and I'm very happy I found it!